# Find a file by a text that is included in the file name

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a directory that looks similar to the following

```
xlsx-modules
├── 0-99
├── 100-199
│   ├── dr111.xls
│   ├── DR115.xls
│   └── DR130.xls
├── 200-299
└── 300-399
    └── DR303.xlsx
```

I try to get the path to the file where the file name includes a code. for example a search with code 111 should return `xlxs-modules/100-199/dr111.xls`

I have searched for information or an example but without success,  could guide me on how to achieve this. Greetings and thanks

Comment: Delete that last paragraph.  We know you searched and we know that you don't have an answer for your question, and we also know you want to know how to achieve what you are describing (or else you wouldn't be posting here, right?)

Comment: This is a two step problem. First, you need to get a list of the files/folders recursively (dirents). Then you need to search for your 'code' in each of these file paths. (using regex or exact string matching).

Comment: Thanks for answering and the idea I just solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I got to solve this problem by implementing

```
import * as fs from "fs";
import { join } from "path";

export function getFiles() {
  const files: string[] = [];

  function collectFiles(directory: string) {
    const fileList = fs.readdirSync(directory);

    for (const fileListElement of fileList) {
      const absolutePath = join(directory, fileListElement);

      if (fs.statSync(absolutePath).isDirectory()) {
        collectFiles(absolutePath);
      } else {
        files.push(absolutePath);
      }
    }
  }

  collectFiles(`${process.cwd()}/xlsx-modules`);

  return files;
}
```

Recursively this function gets a list of the files within the directories, I get a result like this

```
[
  "/home/a123/projects/xlsx-modules/100-199/dr115.xls",
  "/home/a123/projects/xlsx-modules/100-199/DR130.xls",
  "/home/a123/projects/xlsx-modules/100-199/DR111.xls",
  "/home/a123/projects/xlsx-modules/300-399/DR303.xlsx"
]
```

I use this function to get the files path and then do some string matching

```
getModuleBy(code: string) {
  const files: string[] = getFiles();
  const file = files.find((file) => file.includes(code));

  if (!file) {
    throw new NotFoundException(`Module with code ${code} not found`);
  }

  return file;
}
```

Comment: If it's guaranteed your directory structure has the number range for the code you are looking for it would be faster to use that to your advantage and only look in the appropriate directory.   It would only really matter if you had dozens of directories with thousands of files each.  Also it would be better to pass the search criteria to your function so you can test there and not add every file in the whole path to an array in memory before looping through the array again to search for matching files.